# Virtualbox - Multiple controllers with disks

Tags: windows, boot, virtualbox

Using **Virtualbox 6.0**, I created a VM with a SCSI controller, added a optical drive and a hard disk, and installed Windows 7 64 bit on it. It's working just fine.

Now I need, for testing purposes, add a SATA controller with an "empty" disk. Here is what I did:

[image]

But after including the new controller and disk, the boot do not recognize the first SCSI disk with Windows 7 anymore:

[image]

Please, how can I configure the VM to boot from SCSI disk instead of the SATA disk?

Thanks!

Comment: On the System/Sistema tab you can specify the boot order of all VM devices. In this list move your old non-empty disk to the top.

Comment: @Robert, the new hard disk is not showed in the boot order menu. The only options I have is floppy disk, optical disk, hard disk and lan. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: May be something is wrong with the VM definition. I would try to re-create it.

Comment: I do not think multiple hard disk options will ever be shown in boot order menu. I have several VMs, some with multiple SATA disks, and I already checked and there is only one "hard disk" option in this menu. Please, can someone confirm?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this can help, but reading one of the VBOX file i have, it has:

```
...
<StorageController name="SATA" type="AHCI" PortCount="4" useHostIOCache="false" Bootable="true" ...>
...
```

Not sure, but did you tried manually setting `Bootable="false"` instead of `Bootable="true"`?

It affects all disks on that controller, not only one disk on it; so that controller is not used at boot time for booting from it.

Please note i did not see any checkbox on the storage GUI config (Windows host) where that can be changed, so i change it on the VBOX file with a notepad.

I neither find that option explained on VirtualBox OnLine Manual:
https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch03.html#settings-storage.

There are a lot of options not documented on the manual, that is why (almost all the times) i edit the VBOX by hand instead of using the GUI, as same as for setting `autoReset="false"` on `<HardDisk uuid="{...}" location="Snapshots/{...}.vdi" format="VDI" autoReset="true"/>` to avoid the virtual disk be reset when power on the Virtual Machine.

`Bootable="false"` looks a very simple configuration change but maybe it also works for you as for me; what is difficult is to find it on the manual (at least i did not find it on the manual), neither i find on the GUI an option for that controller to be not booteable, but on the VBOX file there is it with default value as `Bootable="true"`.